# Preventing/minimising damage from beer spills

Tags: storage

Spilt some beer on a hand of 7 Wonders cards last night, and it had the potential to completely ruin the cards.

As it was, managed to prevent too much serious damage by carefully sliding the cards apart and drying them off with paper towels.

Am wondering generally for boardgames what the best ways to minimise damage from beer spills are - other than being careful not to spill beer.

Comment: I have a simple rule - if you want to put your drink on the table, you are responsible for replacing the game if it's ruined by the drink being spilled (whoever causes the spill).  So if it's out of print, don't do it.  If it's cheap, take the risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially get sleeves for your cards.

In your case it looks like some companies make sleeves specifically for 7 wonders.

Answer (score 1):

In order to protect cards from being damaged in a situation like this you need to take two actions. First and foremost you need to sleeve your cards and generally you can find card sleeves designed for any card game. Second and most importantly you need to be careful with any food/beverages that are going to be in the gaming area. While sleeves may be good at protecting cards they still have openings where liquid and other matter can get in and damage the cards. When this happens you not only have to deal with cleaning the card but most likely have to replace the card sleeve.

In general unless you have a sleeve that can form a water tight seal around the card you will always need to be careful with your food/beverages as the sleeve is just something to help protect.